# AWS S3 file upload with pre-signed url using JavaScript gets 403 Forbidden error(AccessDenied)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to my S3 bucket using JavaScript with pre-signed url.

This is my JavaScript Code:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", event.target.files[0]);
    formData.append("Content-Type", event.target.files[0].type);
    Object.entries(preSignedFields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if ("Content-Type" === key) {
            return;
        }
        formData.append(key, value);
    })
    fetch(presignedUrl, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: formData,
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The constants presignedUrl and preSignedFields come from an api response. When I call the fetch method, I get 403 Forbidden error.

This is headers information from chrome's dev tool, Network > Headers:

```
Request URL: https://_____.s3.amazonaws.com/files/67189b29466c4341b6cdd422578ac9dd
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: _____
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 13:31:37 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2: 0c22DYZoqcxQ9W8X3o8zwhrP+LveBJ2GSJoer5IA0pgo98hkPaMC0gfO9kUJ7LzB4TfECmyl47I=
x-amz-request-id: _____
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 345706
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Host: _____.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

files/{hiding value}
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

{hiding value}
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

{hiding value}
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

{hiding value}
------WebKitFormBoundaryHh0fScf4jkdjsk94--
```

My S3's Cors settings is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I can't find what's wrong with my implementation. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use presigned POST instead

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you give me a bit more detailed explanation, please? Like the method should be post instead of put?

Comment: yes, doc is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html).

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to POST method but now I get this error response. <Code>MalformedPOSTRequest</Code><Message>The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.</Message>